Qt Button to force stop cycle
In the QObject child class I have a function to check internet connection in the infinite loop:
void S3Downloader::downloadFile(const QString &bucketFilePath) {
        ...
        while (!checkInternetConnection()) {
            QThread::sleep(1);
            qDebug() << "Waiting for the Internet connection";
        }

I want to have a button to force stop application. But when I am in the cycle the application is not stopping:
void PlayWindow::onCloseButtonClicked() {
    const QString exitMessage = "Are you sure you want to exit 2040 World Launcher?";
    if (QMessageBox::Yes == QMessageBox::question(this, "CAUTION", exitMessage, QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No)) {
        s3Downloader->stop(); // s3Downloader is an instance of S3Downloader class
        PlayWindow::close();
    }
}


Can't tell for sure without https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , but looks like the only way to stop your loop while (!checkInternetConnection()) is to have checkInternetConnection return true.

Is S3Downloader in a different thread than the main thread? If not the onCloseButtonClicked() will not happen because of the while (!checkInternetConnection()) { ...} won't let the signal process.

@drescherjm S3Downloader  is in the same thread

As pointed out in comments, your infinite loop is "freezing" your application (GUI included), the events cannot be processed since your function does not give the control back to the event loop for the event to be processed.
The best option would be to execute S3Downloader::downloadFile() into a separate thread so that it won't block your application.
If you don't, the last solution would be to replace the QThread::sleep() call with a manual forced processing of the events.
For that purpose you can write a function like:
void wait_s(unsigned int s)
{
    QTime die_time = QTime::currentTime().addSecs(s);
    while(QTime::currentTime() < die_time)
        QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
}

Or alternatively (better):
void wait_s(unsigned int s)
{
    QEventLoop loop;
    QTimer::singleShot(s*1000, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    loop.exec();
}

And you can replace QThread::sleep(1); with wait_s(1); and it should work.
